# Pipe Operator in Linux

Tags: linux, pipe, stdout, stdin, cat

As per my understanding, the pipe operator in Linux takes standard output of the one command and channelizes it to the standard input of the next command. But I have faced one anomaly. 
I am trying to get the content of a file in the standard ouput as below.

`cat file1`

It displays the content. Let's say the content is another file named `file2`.
Now I want to display the content of `file2`.

So to take the advantage of pipe operator, I am trying to execute as below

`cat file1 | cat`

The first cat command should pipe the output (here "file2"). The cat in the subsequent command must accept it from the standard input (here the value is "file2") and print the content of `file2`.

But it displays "file2" only instead of its contents.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do:

```
cat `cat file1`
```

From `man cat`:

> Concatenate FILE(s), or standard input, to standard output.

In other words, if there is a filename provided as parameter, it will display its content to the standard output, otherwise it will just redirect to standard input to the standard output.

In your case, the filename is read from the standard input and it is interpreted as a string to concatenate to the standard output.

The backquotes are used to inject the standard output of a command, i.e:

```
cat `cat file1`
```

is equivalent to

```
cat file2
```

which will dump file2 content to standard output.

Comment: But the result of both "cat file1" and "cat < file1" are same. So even if I mention the FILE or redirect standard input, the contents are displayed(And not file redirection in the latter as ypou said). Thanks for the alternative approach.

Comment: `< file1` will put the content of the file on the standard input, so it is actually equivalent to `cat file1`.
But what you are doing is `cat file1 | cat` which is equivalent to `echo file2 | cat`, which simply forward the string "file2" to the standard output.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `xargs`:

```
cat file1 | xargs cat
```

[XARGS General Commands Manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html)